# Go Declare Variable outside vs Declare Variable Inside Loop

Tags: go

I am a new in programming. I have two examples code in Go and its about loop using range. This is the first example:

```
Program A

type Test struct {
    Text string
}

func main() {
    tests := []Test{
        Test{"Test1"},
        Test{"Test2"},
    }

    var a Test
    for _, test := range tests {
        a = test
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}
```

This is the second example:

```
Program B

type Test struct {
    Text string
}

func main() {
    tests := []Test{
        Test{"Test1"},
        Test{"Test2"},
    }

    for _, test := range tests {
        a := test
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}
```

In the first example 'a' is declared outside the loop, but in the second example 'a' is declared inside the loop. Like in the other programming language, what is the difference between two example program? Is there any optimization difference? Thank you.

Comment: Honest advice: If you are "new in programming" you should basically _never_ think about "optimization difference" of such trivia. Really. Never. Focus on correctness, sensible data structures and algorithms (which have _way_ _larger_ effect on runtime than _any_ microoptimisation) and readability of your code.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope

Answer (score 12):

The variables have different [scopes](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope). It is usually best practice to use the smallest scope possible as in the second example.

There should be no optimization difference.